# Kafka producer future get timeout

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm trying to handle failures in case the producer fails to send message to Kafka :

```java
try {
    Future<RecordMetadata> res = producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, msg.key(), msg));
    log.info("Waiting for confirmation from kafka for message : \n {}",msg.toString());
    record = res.get(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    log.info("Successfully produced message : msg")
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
    log.error("The following message wasnt sent to kafka because of an error : {}", msg.toString(), e);
}
```

When I try to produce a message to a topic that doesn't exist I'm seeing the following  error :

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic just_fake_topic  not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer$FutureFailure.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:1307) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:962) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:862) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar!/:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:750) ~[kafka-clients-2.5.0.jar!/:na]
at com.xx.xx.produceMessage.handleMessage(produceMessage.java:27) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic just_fake_topic not present in metadata after 60000 ms.
```

I'm getting the timeout after 60 seconds not 30 seconds as I configured in the get method of the future object.

I tried also to configure `metadata.max.idle.ms=30000` and `max.block.ms=30000`  in my kafka.properties because I was also getting the following warning for about 5 minutes but it didn't help:

```
2020-06-28 14:31:26.009  WARN 10291 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 695 : {just_fake_topic =UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: maybe try `producer.flush()`, or [specify Kafka configs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597007/2335775)

Comment: in my case, I just start one producer instance and I try to send one message with a topic that doesnt exist. Thats is all..

Comment: Setting `max.block.ms` should work. The producer did not return until 60 seconds passed even you set a smaller `max.block.ms` value? @JeyJ

Comment: indeed. I set it to 10000 and still it was returned only 60 seconds after.. In addition, the future.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS) didnt actually take 10 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The exception might be getting thrown from the Kafka network thread.

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/apache-kafka/content/kafka-producer-internals-Sender.html

Maybe provide a callback as a second parameter for send.
Note: callback will run on the kafka network thread.

[Kafka Producer : Handle Exception in Async Send with Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56185120/kafka-producer-handle-exception-in-async-send-with-callback)